# Trying to recover my Ubuntu VM. initramfs prompt

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, initramfs, fsck

Last time I used my ubuntu VM, it didn't shut down properly.
Now the VM is no more booting up properly.
Booting it with default setting gives journal errors (sorry I'm not able to have captures)
Searching in the net, I found that I could try to do a fsck check.
So I boot with shift key pressed and selected the _recovery boot menu.
After some errors, the initramfs prompt was shown and I tried fsck /dev/sda1 -y
[image: mount and fsck commands]

Seems that it is not sucessfull, and I can't exit the initramfs prompt, if I type exit, it goes back to initramfs prompt.
I hope I can recover it